# Cambiar el precio de un artículo pero no realizar la consulta de modificar

Tags: php, html, mysql

Este código manda a llamar los productos de mi tabla asi como la ruta de la imagen:

```php
<?php 
   
   require 'config/config.php';
   
   require 'config/database.php';
   
   
   $db = new Database();
   $con = $db->conectar();
   
   
   $Id = $_GET['Id'] ?? $_POST['Id'] ?? '';
   
   if ($Id == '') {
       header("Location: index_admi.php");
       exit;
   }
   
               $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT Nombre, Código, Descuento, Precio FROM productoszir WHERE Id=? AND Activo=1 LIMIT
1");
               $sql->execute([$Id]);
               $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
               $Nombre = $row['Nombre'];
               $Código = $row['Código'];
               $Precio = $row['Precio'];
               $Descuento = $row['Descuento'];
               $Precio_desc = $Precio - (($Precio * $Descuento) / 100);
               $dir_Recursos = 'Recursos/Productos/' . $Id . '/';
               $rutaImg = $dir_Recursos . 'corona.png';
   
               if (!file_exists($rutaImg)) {
                   $rutaImg = 'Recursos/no-photo.png';
               }
   
               $Recursos = array();
               $dir = dir($dir_Recursos);
   
               while (($archivo = $dir->read()) != false) {
                   if ($archivo != 'corona.png' && (strpos($archivo, 'png') || strpos($archivo, 'jpeg'))) {
                       $imagenes[] = $dir_Recursos . $archivo;
                   }
               }
   
   
               $dir->close();
   
?>
```

Aquí empieza el código HTML. Me gustaría saber en cuál de los tres códigos está mi error o el porqué de que no me deja actualizar el precio del producto:

```html
   <body id="body">
   
   
       <section class="modificar">
           <h5 class="modi">Modificar</h5>
           
       </section>
   
   
   
   
       <main>
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">
                       <div class="card shadow-sm" style="width: 22rem; height:34rem; margin-left:68%;">
                           
                           <img src="<?php echo $rutaImg; ?>" class="d-block w-100">
                           
                           <form class="card-body" method="post" action="modificarPrecio.php">
   
                           <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?= $Id?>" >
   
                           <?php include "./modificar_producto.php"; { ?> 
                               
                           <h5 class="nom"><?php echo $Nombre; ?></h5>
                           
                           <p class="code"><?php echo $Código; ?></p>
                               
   
                           <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" class="precio" value="<?php echo MONEDA . number_format ($Precio, 2,
   '.', ','); ?>" >
                 
   
                        
   
                               
   
                           <?php } ?>
   
                           <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" name="actualizar" class="btn btn-primary">
                               
                           </form>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </main>
```

Este es mi código de la consulta que está en un archivo que se llama *Modificar_Producto*. Cuando le doy a actualizar me manda el mensaje de error y no sé qué está mal:

```php
<?php
       $db = new Database();
       $con = $db->conectar();
       
       
       if (!empty($_POST)) {
       
         $Id = trim($_POST['Id']);
         $Precio = trim($_POST['precio']);
       
         $sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE productoszir SET Precio ='$Precio' WHERE Id=$Id ");
                 if($sql == $Id){
                   header("Location:index.php");
                 }else{
                   echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>Error al modificar datos</div>";
                 }
           }
       
         
       ?>
```

Comment: ¿Se te ocurrió hacer un `echo` del error en cuestión? Sin ver el error, tampoco sabemos qué puede estar sucediendo. Por cierto, tu consulta es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL.

Comment: y que error te estaría mostrando?

Comment: Solo me marca errores cuando esta mal el código, solo al darle actualizar me dice que no han sido modificados los datos y ya.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí por que colocas el signo "=" ?

```
 <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?= $Id?>" >
```

Si esto esta en html, creo que lo correcto seria

```
 <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<? echo $Id; ?>" >
```

Espero haber ayudado

Saludos

Comment: PHP permite imprimir la variable utilizando <?= $variable ?> sin necesidad del echo. Ambas maneras son correctas.

Comment: @RicardoPortillo ah genial, tengo conocimiento muy básico de php, ahora aprendí esto. Gracias!